# Macro similar to SIMD instruction

Tags: c, macros

I' trying to create some macros that are somehow similar to SIMD intrinsics. And the reason why I want to create these macros is that I'm working with a simulator called "Gem5" that does not support SIMD.

Well, first of all, i created a structure that defines a vector of 4 packed single precision floating point elements like so:

```
  typedef struct
  {
  float vec1;
  float vec2;
  float vec3;
  float vec4;
  } __m128 __attribute__((aligned(16)));
```

then I've created the ADD macro:

```
   #define __M128_MM_ADD_PS(dest, a,b)  \
  {                                    \
  (dest)->vec1 = (a)->vec1 + (b)->vec1; \
  (dest)->vec2 = (a)->vec2 + (b)->vec2; \
  (dest)->vec3 = (a)->vec3 + (b)->vec3; \
  (dest)->vec4 = (a)->vec4 + (b)->vec4; \
  }
```

and another macro for storing the results in a float array:

```
  #define __M128_MM_MOVA_PS(dest, a) \
  { \
  dest[0] = a->vec1; \
  dest[1] = a->vec2; \
  dest[2] = a->vec3; \
  dest[3] = a->vec4; \
  }
```

and to them I've declared the variables as **__m128** and a float array to store the results, this way(a little example):

```
 void foo(){
 __m128 bfly0_rv, x_n2_vec, x_N2_vec;
 float *x;

 __M128_MM_ADD_PS(bfly0_rv,x_n2_vec,x_N2_vec);
 __M128_MM_MOVA_PS(&x[n2],bfly0_rv);
 }
```

and I'm getting these kind of error messages:

for the ADD macro
**error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘__m128’)
   (dest)->vec4 = (a)->vec4 + (b)->vec4;**

for the storing macro
**error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘__m128’)
   dest[3] = a->vec4;**

Anyone could have an idea about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your macros will work with pointers to `__m128`, but you pass just `__m128` not `__m128 *`. Just replace `->` with `.` inside macros or prepend macro arguments with `&`:

```
__M128_MM_ADD_PS(&bfly0_rv, &x_n2_vec, &x_N2_vec);
__M128_MM_MOVA_PS(&x[n2], &bfly0_rv);
```

Also don't forget to enclose `dest` and `a` in braces in `__M128_MM_MOVA_PS`.

P.S. It would be better to use `do { ... } while(0)` instead of `{ ... }` in macro definitions.

Comment: All the errors are gone except for the Storing macro it shows me the following message: **error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector  dest[0] = a.vec1** and it's pointing on dest[0].

Comment: @A.nechi Did you add braces around `dest`? Without them it expands to `&x[n2][0]` that is surely not what you want.

Comment: you are so great :)